# Game Export Tool like in Maya LT Update 2

Tags: export

Hi I'm new to blender and I was wondering if Blender has something like the game export tool like in Maya LT. What I'm interested in is the ability to export a fbx with animation clips already  defined. This is really important because I'm using this with the Unity game Engine and it would help a lot in speeding up development.

Here is a video of what I'm talking about.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDW_-ACddd4

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried drag and dropping the .blend into Unity?  I think that's what people are doing.  It's supposed to activate the Blender .FBX exporter automatically.

Comment: I do imagine though for this to work you will have to have an official build that is packed with an installer so it can be located by the system path.  Just thought I should note this since Blender is also available as an archive and can be run without installation but Blender won't be found be Unity unless you manually add it to the system path.